# How to apply fixed-header prop to v-table if height of 100vh is not possible?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using Vuetify and have some content above a table. The table should have a [`fixed-header`](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tables/#fixed-header) but this requires a `height` prop. A height of `100%` didn't work and I can't use `100vh` because I have some content above.

[Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-alert type="info" title="some other content goes here" />
      <v-table :fixed-header="true" height="100%"> <!-- height=100% doesn't work -->
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="i in 100">
            <td>x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </v-table>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Do you have any ideas how to setup a fixed header with a correct height?

---

I think the answer of [Igor Moraru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75343985/19698303) is almost correct. The problem is that it is not able to deal with new table rows joining the table.

[Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to compute the table height anyway. One way is to substract the alert height from the container height. What is left is the table height.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main ref="maincontainer">
      <v-alert ref="alert" type="info" title="some other content goes here" />
      <v-table :fixed-header="true" :height="height">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="i in 100">
            <td>x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </v-table>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import {ref, onMounted} from "vue"
export default {
  setup(){
    let maincontainer = ref(null)
    let alert = ref(null)
    let height = ref('500px')
    
    onMounted(() => {
      let mainHeight = maincontainer.value.$el.clientHeight
      let alertHeight = alert.value.$el.clientHeight
      height.value = `${mainHeight - alertHeight}px`
    })
    
    return {
      maincontainer,
      alert,
      height
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Fixed [reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

UPDATE:

---

For a more generic solution (independent of the intermediate elements between the table and the container) you can get the position of the table into the viewport (using `getBoundingClientRect`) and calculate the top and bottom offsets, then subtract them from the viewport height. This way you don't care about what elements are above or below the table but only about the space that they require.

Note: For this solution to work, initially the table should not have a fixed height (or 100% height).

UPDATE:

---

Refactored the solution to allow recomputing the table height on demand.

The main points to consider: using a `computed` is not applicable for this situation because the css props are not reactive in Vue. Instead make the computing in a dedicated function and call it when needed (you can trigger it even from a window resize watcher).

Used the OP setup for a more focused solution.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed, onMounted, nextTick } from "vue";
import TheAlert from "./TheAlert.vue";

const props = defineProps<{ mainContainer: VMain }>();

const tableComponent = ref<VTable>();
const values = ref([]);

const tableHeight = ref(null)
  
const refreshTableHeight = async () => {
  if (!tableComponent.value) {
   tableHeight.value = null;
  }
  // Unset table height and wait for it to rerender
  tableHeight.value = null
  await nextTick()
  
  // Recompute the table height with new data
  const mainRectangle = props.mainContainer.$el.getBoundingClientRect();
  const tableRectangle = tableComponent.value.$el.getBoundingClientRect();

  const topOffset = tableRectangle.top;
  const bottomOffset = mainRectangle.bottom - tableRectangle.bottom;

  tableHeight.value = window.innerHeight - bottomOffset - topOffset;

}

function insertNewRow() {
  values.value.push(new Date());
  refreshTableHeight()
}
onMounted(() => {
  refreshTableHeight()
})

</script>

<template>
    <the-alert />
    <v-container>
        <v-btn @click="insertNewRow">Insert new row</v-btn>
    </v-container>
    <v-table ref="tableComponent" fixed-header :height="tableHeight"> <!-- Do not format here the height to allow for null values -->
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="v in values" :key="v">
          <td>{{ v }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </v-table>
</template>
```

FIXED [reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

Comment: That's a nice idea. But is it not possible to tell the table to fix the header if a scrollbar appeared .. ?

Comment: Otherwise: Do you think your solution is "cleaner" or maybe this approach? ( I'm sorrry, I only know how to do it with Tailwind ) https://play.tailwindcss.com/6FfaGRil62

Comment: this is not a pure css problem. your tailwind example is cleaner if you have to deal with simple divs. When dealing with framework components you have two options: stick with provided configuration options or dig into framework css classes and set them manually. In the latter case, you have to have a very good understanding of framework architecture and also to track any change in such architecture to ensure your app does not break. When working with Vuetify, I found most solutions based on framework API to be more clean and reliable than the ones trying to change the internal css classes.

Comment: Hey Igor, I tried to apply your solution but unfortunately it didn't work. I think the margins and paddings are causing problems

Comment: I will update my question soon, with a reproduction link

Comment: @baitendbidz I updated my answer with a more generic solution. see if it helps

Comment: that solution is even better :) Unfortunately it only works with your reproduction link. My table height is always exactly `0`

Comment: I will update my question with a new reproduction link on my example

Comment: it's working in your example (shortened) `shorturl.at/mRW04`. As I wrote in the updated anwer the initial height of the table should be unset or 100%, so the the correct bottomOffset can be calculated. return null instead of 0 in the computed ref and it should work.

Comment: ah you are right. Unfortunately this solution is not able to deal with new rows :( I need to fetch the data first. I added a button to the example `shorturl.at/ijKOY` and updated my question

Comment: @baitendbidz I updated my answer to allow for on demand recompute of table height. I was reluctant from the start to use a computed because there was no reactive value in it that could've trigger a reevaluation of the computed value (css props are not reactive). also pay attention to `:height` table prop. hope it helps

Comment: that's pretty awesome :) A small sidenote: I used a watcher on the data instead, worked for me at least :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by calculating the height on the fly using [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function. You have to calculate the pixels of the elements that are above the `v-data-table` and then subtract it from 100vh.

```
height="calc(100vh - 60px)"
```

In Vue - You can get the element height dynamically by attaching a `ref` to it and then access the `clientHeight`.

```
this.$refs.alertBox.$el.clientHeight
```

This will return `60` as per the alert box component you added.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
  template: '#app-template'
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@vuetify/nightly@4.0.0-next-20230205.0/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@vuetify/nightly@4.0.0-next-20230205.0/dist/vuetify.css"/>

<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <v-app>
    <v-alert type="info" title="some other content goes here" />
      <v-table fixed-header height="calc(100vh - 60px)">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="i in 100">
            <td>x</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </v-table>
  </v-app>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I think two problems remain. `First`: Would it even be possible to replace `60px` with a dynamic height? E.g. the alert component height? `Second`: What about other spacings like margin or padding? Please have a look at this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75302652/how-to-apply-fixed-header-prop-to-v-table-if-height-of-100vh-is-not-possible/75360032#comment132971031_75343985 and my updated question

Comment: @baitendbidz `First :` You can add dynamic height instead of `60px` by calculating it dynamically. Just for a demo purpose I just suggested a solution to make it work. `Second :` You have to find all the remaining components heights dynamically and combined all those and then subtract from the `100vh`, you will get the table height dynamically.

Comment: I tried your approach ( shortened url ) shorturl.at/ktAEU and now I'm facing the same problems as mentioned in `second`. How would you fix this given sample?

Comment: @baitendbidz This is a very interesting problem, I spent almost 1 hour on this but still did not get luck on `second` part. I will try again after some time and will let you know if I find something.